# Definition of Initial Source

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading the definition of an initial source from the book "The Joy of Cats" by Adamek et al. The author say that if ${\bf A}$ is a concrete category over ${\bf X}$ (with underlying functor $U$), a source $(f_i: A \longrightarrow A_i)_{i \in I}$ is said initial if a ${\bf X}$-morphism $f: U(B) \longrightarrow U(A)$ is an ${\bf A}$-morphism whenever $f_i \circ f: U(B) \longrightarrow U(A_i)$ is an ${\bf A}$-morphism.

Well, something seems to be strange in this definition. I know that $f$ is a ${\bf X}$-morphism. Now, it could happen that $U(g)=f$, where $g: \tilde B \longrightarrow \tilde A$, with $\tilde A,\tilde B$ are different from $A$ and $B$. Thus, what does the composition $f_i \circ f$ actually denote? For each $i \in I$, I must check any possible composition $f_i \circ g$, with $U(g)=f$, and verify that it is an ${\bf A}$-morphism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should say $U(f_i) \circ f : U(B) \to U(A_i)$. The condition that this is an $\mathbf{A}$-morphism means that it is the image of a (unique) morphism $B \to A_i$. Similarly, that $ f$ is an $\mathbf{A}$-morphism means that that it is the image of a (unique) morphism $B \to A$. No other objects except for $A,A_i,B$ of $\mathbf{A}$ are involved here. So the answer to your specific question is "No".